# English word or proverb for expressing a surplus of mental resources in a person?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, proverbs, danish

In Danish we say that some people have a lot of "*overskud*" (surplus) or "*mentalt overskud*" (mental surplus) if they are able to help and look after others, even though they may be very busy themself.

I've found the translation *surplus of mental resources* online - but it seems like a literal translation and I don't feel it conveys exactly what I mean.

Is there a word or proverb that expresses this better?

Comment: It seems that your translation is literally correct but we are losing something. What kind of mental resources are we talking about? I don't think that intelligence or intellect fit here so are we talking about altruism, as was mentioned, or caring, compassion, concern for others, empathy with others, sensitivity to the needs or feeling of others? In general, emotional stuff.

Comment: Hi Danc, welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.